# Portable Web Cam Not Working on Skype Video Call

Tags: 16.04, video, skype, webcam, portable

I use Ubuntu 16.04, and I try to make video call using Skype via my portable web cam (Logitech C525). But even the web cam already plugged in, Skype prefers my built-in front camera rather than the portable web cam. No option for me to choose the portable camera even in the "Audio and Video Settings".

There's no problem when without Skype since the "cheese webcam booth" automatically detect the portable web cam. But I need it when on Skype. Please help anyone...